# Executar funções sem o evento click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para executar determinada função sem precisar esperar o usuário clicar no botão?

Por exemplo, caso o `input` *username* esteja vazio, adicionar uma `div` e quando não estiver mais vazio a `div` é destruída, isso sem nenhum button, sem ser preciso clicar.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que vc tá procurando a função `keypress`. Criei aqui um pequeno fiddle, vê se é tipo isso que vc tá procurando: http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/aVyuB/101/ ?

Comment: Basicamente, precisa *bind* para outro evento - `click` é apenas uma de vários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho meio desnecessário utilizar [JQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) nesse caso, você poderia obter o resultado desejado utilizando apenas `JavaScript` puro....

Bom, de qualquer forma uma solução alternativa utilizando apenas `JavaScript`, sem `Jquery`

```js
window.sumirDiv = function(){
  var campo = document.getElementById("campo").value;

  if(campo.length < 1) div.style.display = "block"; 
  else div.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

```html
<input id="campo" type="text" onkeyup="sumirDiv()" style="float:left"/>
<div id="div" style="display:block">*Campo Obrigatorio</div>
```

---

Alterei a função para verificar no `onkeyup`, desse jeito a verificação só é feita apos a tecla ser solta.

> `onkeydown` -> função é acionada quando o usuário está pressionando uma tecla
>
> `onkeypress` -> função é acionada quando o usuário pressiona uma tecla
>
> `onkeyup` -> função é acionada quando o usuário solta uma tecla

Answer (score 3):

Resolveria o problema que você mencionou utilizando o evento onkeypress no input ou a partir do jQuery com o método keypress caso esteja vazio ou não vazio, exemplo:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputText">
<div id="conteudo">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#inputText').keypress(function (){
    if (this.value != ''){
        $('#conteudo').innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        $('#conteudo').innerHTML = 'O campo não está preenchido';
    }
});
```

Caso preferir pode-se utilizar o método .remove quando não estiver vazio, porém quando estiver vazio novamente a div não será encontrada e consequentemente não será preenchida quando o usuário deixar o campo vazio, exemplo:

```
$('#conteudo').remove();
```

Espero que tenha lhe ajudado, qualquer dúvida estamos aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Um outro exemplo, espero que ajude, este utiliza o metodo remove e add uma Classe e a função keyup.

**CSS:**

```
.notempty{
background-color:#0F0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
}

.empty{
background-color:#F00;
width:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
    <input type="text" />
    <p id="warning"></p>
```

**JQUERY:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#warning").addClass("empty");
            $(":text").keyup(function(){

                if(this.value != '')
                {
                    $("#warning").removeClass("empty");
                    /*remova addclass e terá o efeito esperado
                    $("#warning").addClass("notempty");*/
                }
        });
    });
```